# Kill and Clean a thread that calls a method?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is what I am trying to do:

- UI with start/stop button,
- when start/stop is clicked, start or stop a class method.

This class method is a method that calls a `scheduleAtFixedRate` and also contains a while that checks for a condition. This loops until it found the condition.

How can I make this whole process controlled by the user (in a nice and efficient way)?

Optimally I want to do this:

- Start and call start Method
- Stop and call cleanup Method

If I call the method directly from the UI, it freezes it (because of the while loop).

Now, I tried calling the method from inside a new Thread's `run()` method, 
and this works, but when stopping and calling the thread again, `IllegalThreadStateException` is thrown.

I also tried `if (thread.isAlive()) { mainThread = new Thread(mainThread);}`
But this also doesn't work (it throws the same error as before).

What can I do? I am trying not to make the method that I call a thread/runnable, because it would fill half of it with try/catches (making the code pretty much unreadable).

EDIT: 
This is what I came up with. As said It doesn't work the second time.
Missing variables are simple and can be inferred.

### UI CODE:

```
//Other code
 //Thread
mainThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         try
                {
                    magicalManager.execute(2);
                }
            catch (Exception e){}
     }

});



ActionListener StartStopAL = new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
            {

                if (startButtonStatus == false) {
                    startButton.setText("Start");
                    startButtonStatus = true;

                            mainThread.interrupt();
                            TaskScheduler.getScheduledExecutorService().shutdown();

                }
                else if (startButtonStatus == true) {
                    startButton.setText("Stop");
                    startButtonStatus = false;
                    if (mainThread.isAlive()) {
                    mainThread = new Thread(mainThread);
                    }
                    mainThread.start();

                }

            }
    };

//Add action listener to startButton
//Other code
```

### Class Code:

```
public class magicalManager 
{
    public static void execute(int ID) throws Exception {
        //run scheduleAtFixedRate
        while(...)
        {
            if (...){
            break;
            }
        }
        return
    }
    public static void KillManager(){
    //kill scheduleAtFixedRate
    }
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter, care to explain why?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant source code from your program.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @JimGarrison what is not clear to you exactly? By the way, I am NOT seeking debugging help. I am asking how I could do a specific thing in a neat and efficient way. So yeah, in this case code IS NOT NEEDED (I am adding it though to get more specific answers). I have no idea where you inferred I was 'seeking debugging help'.

Answer (score 1):

Once a thread's `run()` method has completed,
the thread can never be restarted . In fact, at that
point the thread moves into a dead state. In the dead state, the thread can never be restarted.

The Thread object might still be on the heap, as a
living object that you can call other methods on (if
appropriate), but the Thread object has permanently
lost it's "threadness". In other words, there is no longer a
separate call stack, and the Thread object is no longer
a thread. It's just an object, at that point, like all other
objects.

But, there are design patterns for making a pool of
threads that you can keep using to perform different
jobs. But you don't do it by restarting a dead thread.

Comment: So restarting a dead thread is not an option. Okay got that, but what could I do then? I effectively want to close/reboot EVERYTHING in that class when stopping/starting.

Comment: Provide me with some source code to better understand the problem.

Comment: It's coming, do not worry.

Comment: Updated, check it out. If you need more I can provide it to you (although I think the start/stop button logic should be enough)